# Number of unordered pairs from set of size $n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a set $\displaystyle S=\{s_{i} ,s_{2} ,\dotsc ,s_{n}\}$.

Each two set have a cost $\displaystyle c\{s_{i} ,s_{j}\}$ and a gain $\displaystyle g\{s_{i} ,s_{j}\}$. They are underdered, such that: $\displaystyle c\{s_{i} ,s_{j}\} =c\{s_{j} ,s_{i}\}$. In addition, I only look at the pairs $\displaystyle i\neq j$.

I want to find the number of costs/gains present from the set. How can I do that?

I though of doing it logically, and I argued the following:

There are $\displaystyle n-1$ couples available with $\displaystyle s_{1}$ present.

There are $\displaystyle n-2$ couples available with $\displaystyle s_{2}$ present (if I don't count the one already taken from $\displaystyle s_{1}$).

There are $\displaystyle n-3$ couples available with $\displaystyle s_{3}$ present (if I don't count the one already taken from $\displaystyle s_{3}$,$\displaystyle s_{2}$).

I get: $\displaystyle m=n-1+n-2+n-3+\dotsc +n-n=n^{2} -\frac{n}{2}( n+1) =\frac{n^{2} -n}{2}$.

But I also found online the formula to pick $\displaystyle 2$ undored pairs as: $\displaystyle \binom{n}{2} =n( n-1) =n^{2} -n$.

Which also makes sense to me as having $\displaystyle n$ options for the first one and $\displaystyle ( n-1)$ for the second.

So I did I get half the result in the first place? Where is the mistake?

Comment: $n(n-1)$ is the number of 2-permutations from $n$ elements. Since you want them to be unordered, you have to divide by two = $2!$. The formula for choosing unordered $k$-pairs from $n$ elements of a set is "$n$ choose $k$" = ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

Comment: The correct formula for $\binom{n}{2}$ is $$\frac{n!}{2!(n - 2)!} = \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2)!}{2 \cdot 1 \cdot (n - 2)!} = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$$